# photo library loading in ios

Tags: ios, photo, alassetslibrary

I have this static method to return all the photos of my album. The thing is when I run this app, the function runs twice: once returning no images, and once putting the images in the all images array but not getting to the return. I'm confused, what am I doing wrong?

```
 + (NSMutableArray *)photosAssest
   {
     NSMutableArray *allImages = [NSMutableArray new];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = AssatLibaryHelper.defaultAssetsLibrary;



    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {

       NSInteger numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];
       if (numberOfAssets > 0)
       {

         for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfAssets-1; i++)
         {
              [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
              {
                  if (result != nil)
                  {
                      UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                      [allImages addObject:thumbnail];
                  }
              }];
         }

     }

 }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {

 }];


return allImages;
```

}

Comment: `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` is asynchrone, see the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:

Comment: so how can i run in single threaded or how can i know when it ended?

Comment: Well, you're yourself using `[group numberOfAssets]`, so you may know when it finished.